# kali linux- proxychains version

Tags: kali-linux

I've got proxychains 3.1 . while running 
proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com

Can't connect to any server. All connections are denied. I've uncommented dynamic chain and comment strict chain. Still same problem. I've tried researching about it online. I saw something like to update to new version.

Can anyone give some info on the matter? I'm a new user, and I'm starting to struggle. Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't mention it in your question, I assume you don't have anything other running than proxychains.

Imagine Proxychains as a connection between a proxy and an application.
If it isn't set-up, it tries to redirect the communucation of the invoked application (Firefox) to a non-existing proxy and the connection gets refused. To have an easy setup, you could install tor (https://www.torproject.org/) and let it run in the background. Now you need to configure proxychains to use tor which (by default) listens on port 9050.

As you're already working on Kali-Linux, Tor should be pre-installed and should be able to be started by executing "tor" inside of a terminal.

**Check if all is set-up correctly:**

check for tor service:

```
ngs@ngs:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep tor
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1922/tor
```

check for correct configuration of the /etc/proxychains.conf file:

```
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
```

run it:

```
ngs@ngs:~$ proxychains google-chrome "check.torproject.org"
```

[image: google-chrome running via proxychains (tor)]

**Updating from source**

If you want to update proxychains to the newest version (from source), you first have to remove the existing package and compile a new one:

```
ngs@ngs:~$ sudo apt-get purge proxychains
```

Download the newest version from http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/, untar and build it

```
ngs@ngs:~$ tar -xvf proxychains-3.1.tar.gz
proxychains-3.1/
proxychains-3.1/AUTHORS
proxychains-3.1/COPYING
proxychains-3.1/ChangeLog
.
.
ngs@ngs:~$ cd proxychains-3.1/
ngs@ngs:~$ ./configure
ngs@ngs:~$ make
```

To install:

```
ngs@ngs:~$ sudo make install
```

Check the version and config of Proxychains again.

Comment: actually i do have tor set up on my machine. tor is working and i'm able to browse any page with it. however, when i use " proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com" all connection are denied .

i've added "socks5 207.0.0.1 9050" to the proxychains.conf file . but i still get the same problem . all connections are denied and it says either denied or timeout . i've restarted tor a couple of times but still same problem . 
any help with this greatly appreciated

Comment: so, is it running and is proxychains configured to use it?

Comment: i will edit my answer as you just pointed out that you set-up everything correctly... maybe an update will really help...

Comment: You added "socks5 207.0.0.1 9050" to the configuration? That's not your local address (loopback). It should be 127.0.0.1